# is it possible with listbox on start go to a particular line?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I want this listbox to go to the current date on start.
[image]

I am using this to generate the calendar.

```
import holidays
    def date_range(date1, date2):
        listboxMain.delete(0, tk.END)
        us_holidays = holidays.UnitedStates(state="PA")
        
        
        def daterange(date1, date2):
            for n in range(int((date2 - date1).days) + 1):
                yield date1 + timedelta(n)
    
        for i, dt in enumerate(daterange(date1, date2)):
            holiday = us_holidays.get(dt)
            if not holiday:
                holiday = ""
    
            day, date, month, year = dt.strftime('%A %d %B %Y').split()
            line = f'{day:10s} {date} {month:>10s} {year:>7} {holiday}'
    
            if (datetime.date.today() - dt).days == 0:
                TODAY_INDEX = i
    
            listboxMain.insert(i, line)
            index = listboxMain.get(0, tk.END).index(line)
            # print(line, index, i,"after line insert line 76")
    
        listboxMain.itemconfig(TODAY_INDEX, {'bg': '#cc9900'})
        listboxMain.itemconfig(TODAY_INDEX, {'fg': '#000099'})

    button_calender = tk.Button(lower2_frame, text="Calendar", fg='#99ceff', bg='#32475a', font=(
        'Times', 18), borderwidth =' 8', command=lambda: date_range(A_WEEK_AGO, A_450_DAYS_AHEAD))
```

I have tried to get the current date index with this.

```
def day_today():
        dt = datetime.date.today()
        day, date, month, year = dt.strftime('%A %d %B %Y').split()
        return f'{day:10s} {date} {month:>10s} {year:>7}'
```

index = listboxMain.get(0, tk.END).index(day_today())

But got this error:

```
ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple
```

If i finally get the index, is there a way to auto scroll to the line with the index?

**UPDATE:**
As BryanOakley has hinted I was not using the same format for index to get the current date line.

```
return f'{day:10s} {date} {month:>10s} {year:>7}'
```

Had to be changed to

```
return f'{day:10s} {date} {month:>10s} {year:>7} {holiday}'
```

Now I can finally get scrolling to the current day when the calendar starts with
these 2 lines.

```
index = listboxMain.get(0, tk.END).index(day_today())
listboxMain.see(index)
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `day_today` is returning a string in precisely the same format as the data in the listbox - it doesn't appear to be. Have you verified that `listboxMain.get` is returning what you expect it to return? Please provide a [mcve], and prefereably one that doesn't require the `holidays` module. A few hard-coded lines of text should be enough to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley, you are correct. I was not using the same format.